# esp 32 connection via wifi, with a reactive native expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, wifi, esp32, arduino-esp32

This is my code in reactive native, using Vscode, creating a test app to test the wifi conection:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import TcpSocket from 'react-native-tcp-socket';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

const App = () => {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
  const clientRef = useRef(null);

  // Função para verificar o estado da conexão à rede Wi-Fi
  const checkNetworkStatus = async () => {
    const netInfoState = await NetInfo.fetch();
    setIsConnected(netInfoState.isConnected);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Verifique o status da rede ao montar o componente
    checkNetworkStatus();

    // Assine os eventos de conexão/desconexão da rede
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      setIsConnected(state.isConnected);
    });

    return () => {
      // Limpe os ouvintes ao desmontar o componente
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  // Função para conectar ao servidor ESP32
  const connectToESP32 = () => {
    clientRef.current = TcpSocket.createConnection(
      { host: '192.168.15.19', port: 80 },
      () => {
        console.log('Conectado ao ESP32');
        setIsConnected(true);
      }
    );

    clientRef.current.on('close', () => {
      console.log('Desconectado do ESP32');
      setIsConnected(false);
    });

    clientRef.current.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Erro de conexão:', error);
      setIsConnected(false);
    });
  };

  // Função para enviar "0" para o ESP32
  const sendZero = () => {
    if (isConnected && clientRef.current) {
      if (clientRef.current.connecting) {
        console.log('Aguardando conexão completa...');
      } else {
        clientRef.current.write('0');
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Não conectado ao ESP32');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.statusText}>
        {isConnected ? 'Conectado ao ESP32' : 'Não conectado'}
      </Text>
      <Button title="Conectar ao ESP32" onPress={connectToESP32} />
      <Button title="Enviar 0" onPress={sendZero} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  statusText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default App;
```

in the esp32 the code i am using in the arduinoi IDE is:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>

const char *ssid = "APT 63";
const char *password = "jakson63";
const int serverPort = 80; // Porta do servidor TCP

WiFiServer server(serverPort);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // Conecte-se à sua rede Wi-Fi
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Conectando-se a ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Conectado à rede WiFi");
  Serial.println("Endereço IP: " + WiFi.localIP().toString());

  // Inicialize o servidor TCP
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Aguarde uma conexão de cliente
  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  if (client) {
    Serial.println("Novo cliente conectado");

    // Leia os dados enviados pelo cliente
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        String data = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println("Dados recebidos: " + data);

        // Aqui você pode processar os dados recebidos do aplicativo
        // Neste exemplo, apenas ecoaremos os dados de volta para o cliente

        // Envie os dados de volta para o cliente
        client.print("Você enviou: ");
        client.println(data);
      }
    }

    // Feche a conexão com o cliente
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Cliente desconectado");
  }
}
```

in the serial monitor is:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13260
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4

Conectando-se a APT 63
.
Conectado à rede WiFi
Endereço IP: 192.168.15.19
```

and in the app is running this error:

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of null, js engine:
> hermes

what is this error from, and how can i manage this conection?